# Qual a diferença entre usar ou não um "constraint" no "foreign key"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sintaxe, chave-estrangeira, constraint

Ao criar uma tabela no MySQL usei na criação de campos `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY` como está a seguir para criar a chave estrangeira:

```
CREATE TABLE socio 
(
  id_socio      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  nome          VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  cpf           VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  email         VARCHAR(256),
  id_situacao   INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT pk_id_socio PRIMARY KEY (id_socio),
  CONSTRAINT un_socio_cpf UNIQUE (cpf),
  CONSTRAINT socio_id_situacao_fk_ref FOREIGN KEY (id_situacao) REFERENCES situacao (id_situacao)
);
```

Qual a diferença de na criação de tabelas, usar apenas o `FOREIGN KEY` ou o `FOREIGN KEY` com `CONSTRAINT` para criar chaves estrangeiras?

Comment: Acredito que a diferença é que quando você utiliza `CONSTRAINT <nome> FOREIGN KEY ...` você está declarando explicitamente a *constraint*, ou seja, dando nome a ela. Já na outra situação, o próprio banco de dados se encarrega de nomear a *constraint*. Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652629/differences-between-foreign-key-and-constraint-foreign-key).

Comment: Então não tem diferença correto? Apenas que em um caso vc da um nome e no outro o back escolhe

Comment: Exato! Em termos de funcionalidade não tem diferença nenhuma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cláusula `CONSTRAINT` é usada para dar nome a este restrição de integridade. Só isto, dar um nome da sua escolha.

Mesmo sem ela ainda será uma restrição imposta à tabela, porém o nome será o mesmo do índice associado em `FOREIGN KEY`, e no caso de não ter um índice indicado ele cria um nome baseado no nome da coluna. Neste caso como não tem esse índice sem a `CONSTRAINT` o nome seria gerado a partir da coluna. No seu exemplo o nome dessas restrições serão `pk_id_socio`, `un_socio_cpf`, `socio_id_situacao_fk_ref`.

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Basicamente,  constraint o usuário define um nome para a FK, sem a constraint o sistema gera um nome automaticamente para a FK ?

Comment: Sim, é só isto.

Answer (score 0):

A constraint garante que a integridade dos dados, por exemplo
temos uma tabela X e Y, onde a X tem uma FK com a Y, se você tentar deletar um registro da tabela X sem deletar primeiro da tabela Y os registros que possuem a FK com a X o banco não vai deixar, vai dar erro de constraint violada

Comment: Eu sei como funciona a constraint, os quero saber eh se tem diferença entre constraint foreign key e foreign key